# List not printing as wanted c#

Tags: c#, list, loops

So when i use a for loop to print through my list, it just doesn't print correctly. It says the person's ages are all 59 and not coming out with other ages. The rest of the code in my program is correct and tested with other code but I think there's something wrong here, maybe I'm using the Lists incorrectly?

```
 int teenagersCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Teenagers percentage?"))) / 100;

        int adultsCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Adults percentage?"))) / 100;

        int elderlysCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Elderlys percentage?"))) / 100;

        int teenagersCountNum = (int)(teenagersCountPerc * totalPeople);
        int adultsCountNum = (int)(adultsCountPerc * totalPeople);

int temp1 = teenagersCountNum + adultsCountNum;
for (int i = 0; i < teenagersCountNum; i++) //teens
{
    people.Insert(i, new Person() { FirstName = ("firstName" + i) , LastName = ("lastName" + i), Age = Int32.Parse("16") });  //tried with just integer without parse
}
for (int i = teenagersCountNum; i < temp1; i++) //adults
{
        people.Insert(i, new Person() { FirstName = ("firstName" + i), LastName = ("lastName" + i), Age = Int32.Parse("21") });
}
for (int i = temp1; i < people.Capacity; i++) //elderlys
{
    people.Insert(i, new Person() { FirstName = ("firstName" + i), LastName = ("lastName" + i), Age = Int32.Parse("59") });
}

peopleList.Sort((x, y) => x.Age.CompareTo(y.Age));
            for (int i = 0; i < peopleList.Capacity; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + peopleList.ElementAt(i).FullName);
                Console.WriteLine("Age: " + peopleList.ElementAt(i).Age);
                Console.WriteLine("Paid: " + peopleList.ElementAt(i).Paid);

            }
```

peopleList is the people list...just in a different method using parameters. :) The values are as supposed to be for the variables in temp1.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you print the people? All for loops create new Persons so the only way you can have only people with age 59 is if the first two loops do nothing.

Comment: Check that teenagersCountNum and adultsCountNum are actually the values you expect. If they are not assigned any value, they are 0 and your last loop overwrites it all. You cannot really see the difference since the naming is the same in all three loops (firstName + i).

Comment: More edits done. I think the values are what i expect it seems. :L

Comment: My guess is that `teenagersCountPerc` is zero, because you perform an integer division (e.g. if you enter 20, then `int x = 20 / 100` will give `x = 0`).

Comment: How would I go about changing this?

Comment: @TingAli don't do division with int but with float\double. dont't use Capacity but Length. And why Insert and not just Add?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should (learn to) use a debugger to step through your code. You are quite likely to find that you are not generating elements for the first two lists. Consider your first few lines:

```
int teenagersCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Teenagers percentage?"))) / 100;
int adultsCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Adults percentage?"))) / 100;
int elderlysCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Elderlys percentage?"))) / 100;
```

Suppose that I enter the values 10, 50 and 40 here (why do I need to enter the elderlies percentage, shouldn't it be 100 minus the other two? Did you mean to ask for the total number of people and two percentages?). Then you are performing an integer division:

```
int teenagersCountPerc = 10 / 100 = 0; // Note: integer division
int adultsCountPerc = 50 / 100 = 0;    // Note: integer division
int elderlysCountPerc = 40 / 100 = 0;  // Note: integer division
```

Now the next two lines

```
int teenagersCountNum = (int)(teenagersCountPerc * totalPeople);
int adultsCountNum = (int)(adultsCountPerc * totalPeople);
```

will give `teenagersCountNum = adultsCountNum = 0` meaning that you fill the entire list (`persons.Capacity`) with elderlies.

Fix it by changing your percentages to floating point numbers, e.g.

```
double teenagersCountPerc = (Int32.Parse(GetUserInput("Teenagers percentage?"))) / 100.0;
```

(note that I wrote `100.0` to prevent the division from being performed with integers and converted to double afterwards), or perhaps even allow your users to enter a decimal number to begin with (they might want 30.3% teenagers):

```
double teenagersCountPerc = (Double.Parse(GetUserInput("Teenagers percentage?"))) / 100;
```

(where the `.0` is not strictly needed because the first part of the division makes it a floating point calculation already).

---

#### Side remarks

The usual way to use a list is:

```
var persons = new List<Person>();
```

or, if you already know how many persons you are going to create:

```
var persons = new List<Person>(personCount);
```

and then just add onto the end of the list:

```
persons.Add(new Person() { ... });
```

This does not require you to keep the index at which to insert the next person.
You hardly ever need to `Insert` items, unless you need items to go in some particular position. Here it is especially pointless, since you are going to sort the list afterwards anyway.

Also note that `Capacity` may be larger than what you want, you probably want to fill the list up to some `personCount` variable and after filling it use `Count` instead of `Capacity` to check the number of persons.

Finally, I don't know what `GetUserInput` does, but I suggest putting the `Int32.Parse` inside of it and validating the input. Right now, I presume `GetUserInput` returns a `string` -- if I enter `abcd` then `Parse` will throw an exception and the program will crash. Instead, consider something like

```
int? GetIntegerFromUser()
{
  string input = System.Console.ReadLine();
  int result;
  return int.TryParse(input, out result) ? result : default(int?);
}
```

and handle the case where the result is `null` in your caller.

Comment: BRILLIANT! :) Thank you so much, I'll definitely look into debugging tutorials for Visual Studio! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @TingAli also added some side remarks about other weird things in your code.